# How do you handle bad network on the refresh token calls?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I have an oAuth implementation that works 99% of the time. When it gets into trouble, it is always around refreshing the token over a bad network. My problem comes when the token refresh call does not return. At that point I have no way of knowing where in the flow the call failed.

a) If the call failed before it got to the server, I should re-issue my token update.

b) If the call failed on its way back from the server, no matter what I do I am forced to log the user out because all the tokens I have are now invalidated and I did not receive the new tokens.

Currently I am re-issuing the refresh token call because it has the greatest chance for success. How do most apps handle this situation? Seems like something that would be an issue for most mobile apps, yeah?